# can we use socket.io(that node.js one) in hybrid apps like phonegap/ionic apps

Tags: cordova, socket.io

My question is that can we use and practically whats the difference in running a socket.io based hybrid app on emulator(not on web browser) , will all the stuff that local host etc works same , and it will provide sockets in the same manner?

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io is a JavaScript library that provides a clean abstraction for programming applications with bidirectional client-server communication (as opposed to the normal HTTP request-response style of communication). It uses technology like [WebSocket](https://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html)s when available and gracefully degrades to more traditional server-push techniques like long-polling when the newer technology is not supported.

WebSockets and Socket.io are intended for bidirectional communication between web browsers and HTTP servers. They are not intended for general purpose network socket programming. However, these can be used to develop web applications capable of handling spontaneous delivery of data from such socket based-services by using the HTTP server as an intermediary.

Comment: i meant to say that will it work on native phonegap applications?